# send generated pdf using python report lab and vue js in autoamted way to mail recipent in weekly base

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js

I am generating pdf using report lab in python, when user click generate report in vue js front end page it calls api using python flask to get the pinary_pdf, I want to generate and send pdf to mail recipient every Monday in automated way.

Vue Js function

````
          // this.validateForm()
          // this.$refs.form.validate()
          this.$emit('pdfGenerated', null)
          this.isPdfGenerating = true
          this.isPdfGenerated = false
          let jsonData = {
            key:this.$store.state.key,
            isDraft:isDraft,
            currentWeek:this.currentWeek,
            year:new Date().getFullYear(),
            weeklyTable: this.weeklyTable,
          }
          console.log(jsonData) 
          this.$axios.post(this.$backendUrl + '/weeklyhighlights', jsonData)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.pdfData = { data: response.data }
            this.$emit('pdfGenerated', this.pdfData)
            this.isPdfGenerated = true
            this.isPdfGenerating = false
            
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
              this.isPdfGenerating = false
              this.isPdfGenerated = false
              if (error.response.status==401)
              {
                   this.$emit('unauthorized')
              }
               if (error.response.status==404)
              {
                   window.alert(error.response.data.message)
              }
          })     
          .then(function () {
            
          });

      },

    savePdf: function () {
      var blob = new Blob([this.pdfData.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var fileName ="filename"
        
      link.download = fileName;
      link.click();
    },```
````